How to see the content of an appointment in a queue of commands of AT command
I know i can see the schedule with atq, but this brings me only the timedate of the execution and  not wich command wil be executed.
[root@myserver ~]# atq
1Thu Oct 31 04:45:00 2024 a root

Using at -c 1 it spits all the job, and a lot of configs (at this point for me is only garbage).
Is there any way to see only de pure command that will be executed?

Executing command:
at -c 1|grep -ve '^[A-Z]'

will return  the commands which will be executed. It show also additional commands but strip the long listing of variables
